# Make button hold variable and at end of cycle run code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

```
  void setup() {

  for (int i = 0; i < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[thisPin], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {      
      digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
      delay(10000);
      digitalWrite(1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(2,LOW);
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(4,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(11,LOW);
      delay(10000);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  }
```

We're making an "Advanced Stop Light", so
In the code i need to add it so when the button is pressed at any time, at the end of the cycle it'll run the code for that, How would i do that?

I've tried a couple things, but every time it doesnt work, What would be a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a flag when the button is pressed and then checking at the end of the loop if the flag has been set.

When the flag has been set you know the button has been pushed so you can execute the code. Something like this.

```
boolean buttonPressed = false;

void setup() {    
  for (int i = 0; i < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[thisPin], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {      
      digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
      delay(10000);
      digitalWrite(1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(2,LOW);
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(4,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(11,LOW);
      delay(10000);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      delay(2500);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      if(buttonPressed)
      {
           //code goes here
      }
  }
```

All you need to add above is when your button is pressed set buttonPressed = true

Comment: I did try that, because if the button is pressed at any time before that it wont register it,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the entire cycle to run regardless of whether the button is pressed, THEN the special code to run (or not) depending on whether the button was pressed during the cycle.

If so, you could write a function my_delay(msec) and call it inside the cycle instead of delay. inside my_delay, you would have a loop that tests repeatedly if the button is pressed until the requested time has passed:

```
static int lpressed = 0 ;

void my_repeat(int msec)
{
   long start = millis() ;
   for( ; millis()-start < msec; )
   {
      if (digitalRead(button_pin)==PRESSED)
         lpressed = 1 ;
   }
}
```

Then at the end of the cycle you would simply test (and probably reset) the variable lpressed and act accordingly:

```
void loop()
{
   // your unconditional code goes here
   if (lpressed)
   {
      lpressed = 0 ; // reset so we can check again in next cycle
      // your conditional code goes here
   }
}
```